# Error when using 'make install' command in qbittorrent installation

Tags: command-line, make, error-handling, execute-command, makefile

I am attempting to install qbittorrent software from tar.gz (https://www.qbittorrent.org/download.php) on ubuntu 22.04. I can unpack the zip files, run configure, and make executes just fine, but when I try make install, I get the following error:

```
se7en@se7enubuntu:~/Downloads/qbittorrent-4.4.3.1$ sudo make && make install
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/se7en/Downloads/qbittorrent-4.4.3.1/src/src.pro -qtconf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qt.conf -early QMAKE_CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc QMAKE_CXX=x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ QMAKE_LINK=x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ QMAKE_STRIP=x86_64-linux-gnu-strip QMAKE_QMAKE=/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-qmake PKG_CONFIG=x86_64-linux-gnu-pkg-config -before QMAKE_LRELEASE= ) && make -f Makefile 
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/se7en/Downloads/qbittorrent-4.4.3.1/src'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/se7en/Downloads/qbittorrent-4.4.3.1/src'
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -o Makefile /home/se7en/Downloads/qbittorrent-4.4.3.1/src/src.pro -qtconf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qt.conf -early QMAKE_CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc QMAKE_CXX=x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ QMAKE_LINK=x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ QMAKE_STRIP=x86_64-linux-gnu-strip QMAKE_QMAKE=/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-qmake PKG_CONFIG=x86_64-linux-gnu-pkg-config -before QMAKE_LRELEASE= ) && make -f Makefile install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/se7en/Downloads/qbittorrent-4.4.3.1/src'
/usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake -install qinstall /home/se7en/Downloads/qbittorrent-4.4.3.1/doc/qbittorrent.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/qbittorrent.1
Error copying /home/se7en/Downloads/qbittorrent-4.4.3.1/doc/qbittorrent.1 to /usr/local/share/man/man1/qbittorrent.1: Destination file exists
make[1]: *** [Makefile:6291: install_man] Error 3
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/se7en/Downloads/qbittorrent-4.4.3.1/src'
make: *** [Makefile:59: sub-src-install_subtargets] Error 2
```

I google it, but have nothing about this error codes.

Comment: You need to run second command as `sudo make install` also.

Comment: `qbittorrent` is in the official repositories.  Why would you install it this way? All you need to do is run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install qbittorrent`. Alternatively, you can install it from your GUI software center.

Comment: @Nmath qbittorrent from AppImage have one big bug with drag'n'drop (it is not working), that's why I'm using it

Comment: @MichalPrzybylowicz thanks to you, I always thinking, that sudo extends to the entire line!

Comment: @Nmath sorry, understand it, will add his repo, thanks!